# RAID 0 or btrfs on two SSDs?

Tags: ssd, raid, btrfs, intel-rst

I have two 500 GB SSD's, and I would like to combine the two in some way to have 1 250 GB NTFS partition, and 1 750 GB `btrfs` or `ext4` partition.

As far as I see, I have two options: the Intel Rapid Storage technology included with the computer, which is recognized in Linux as software RAID 0, or have the two drives be logically separate, with the 250 GB partition only on the first disk and use `btrfs` to RAID 0 the 750 GB partition, with 250 GB on the first drive and the full 500 GB on the second.

The things I'm worried about:

- Will TRIM work properly in both of these situations?
- Which will keep the SSDs running quickly the longest?
- Which will have better performance for the Linux partition?
- Any other strange things I should look out for with either?
- Which would be "best practice"?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a production system where safety and reliability is important I'd stick to ext4 type of partitions probably in association with LVM.  I'm not as convinced that btrfs is at the same level of maturity as ext4.

Comment: So are you recommending the Intel RAID 0? Or just no RAID 0 and stick with LVM?